# Receiving no response with JQuery And JavaScript http requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, twilio

I have this code here...

```
 function dequeue(id){

 $.post("dequeue.php",
    {
        Queue: id,
        ConnectTo: "Terri"

    },
    function(data, status){
        document.getElementById("log").innerHTML=callSid +"getting call";
    });
  }
```

When I select a button it executes and will work the first 2 or three times I click the button. After that, it will crash. In my javascript console on Internet Explorer or Chrome, I get an error saying there was an empty response from the server. I am also using the XMLHttpRequest javascript function. I have the exact same results with that as well. Once I get an empty response, I will try to refresh the page and the page won't load. It will take about 5 minutes before the page will load again. I have my hosting with Godaddy on one of their shared servers. I have several domains hosted on that shared server as well. Once I get this error, all of the websites on my shared server return an empty response for about 5 minutes as well. I am very confused. I do not know why the http requests would be causing this crash.

Here is an example of the error I am getting

http://ftstoo.com/Phone/TheFinalTouchSecurity/dequeue.php net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSEf.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send @ jquery.min.js:4f.extend.ajax @ jquery.min.js:4f.each.f.(anonymous function) @ jquery.min.js:4(anonymous function) @ Terri.php:56

```
Request URL:http://ftstoo.com/Phone/TheFinalTouchSecurity/dequeue.php
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Accept:*/*
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Origin:http://ftstoo.com
Referer:http://ftstoo.com/Phone/TheFinalTouchSecurity/Terri.php
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Data
view source
view URL encoded
Queue:Terri
```

Comment: You may have another element in the innerHTML code with the id `log`

Comment: How would that cause the http request to crash? @MaxZoom

Comment: Did not you say that it works first time(s) and then it loops/waits for respond? It is hard to tell what code your innerHTML has.

Comment: I just ran a search on the code and there is only one element with the id of log.

Comment: It is only a button click. So the button executes the function dequeue when it is clicked by the user. No loops. It works the first two or three times you click the button. On the 4th - n clicks it receives an empty response.

Comment: Open up the Developer Tools of your Browser and look at the Network Tab and check the request. See if there's a valid response.

Comment: You need to look at your server logs for when the dequeue.php runs. I don't think it is the clientside code that is causing your problem, merely triggering it

Comment: Ok I just added the error response from the browser to the question. @MInusFour

Comment: If you check the request on the Network Tab of your Developer Tools you can check the exact server response for the client petition which can help you debug your problem.

Comment: @CannonMoyer, that doesn't look like the Server Response but the stack trace of the javascript error.

Comment: I am not seeing anything other than the empty response error. It gives request header information which is what I would expect and an error saying there was an empty response error. @MinusFour

Comment: I don't understand where you are saying the server response error would be. I see the network tab @MinusFour

Comment: Just added one more error response @MinusFour

Comment: @CannonMoyer, [here](http://i.imgur.com/VY5sSQl.png)

Comment: I do know about that error, but the error I am talking about is an empty response error. If you let the page run for a minute or two you will see the error come up automatically on checkCallQueue.php also. It gives the error on checkCallQueue.php and dequeue.php @MinusFour

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87508/discussion-between-minusfour-and-cannon-moyer).